# Is TCP Guaranteed to arrive in order?

Tags: python, tcp, twisted, protocols

If I send two TCP messages, do I need to handle the case where the latter arrives before the former? Or is it guaranteed to arrive in the order I send it? I assume that this is not a Twisted-specific example, because it should conform to the TCP standard, but if anyone familiar with Twisted could provide a Twisted-specific answer for my own peace of mind, that'd be appreciated :-)

Comment: Since TCP has no idea where your messages begin or end, how could it possibly reorder them even if it wanted to?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As long as the two messages were sent *on the same TCP connection*, order will be maintained.  If multiple connections are opened between the same pair of processes, you may be in trouble.

Regarding Twisted, or any other asynchronous event system: I expect you'll get the `dataReceived` messages in the order that bytes are received.  However, if you start pushing work off onto deferred calls, you can, erm... "twist" your control flow beyond recognition.

Answer (score 25):

TCP is connection-oriented and offers its Clients **in-order** delivery. Of course this applies to the connection level: individual connections are independent.

You should note that normally we refer to "TCP streams" and "UDP messages".

Whatever Client library you use (e.g. Twisted), the underlying TCP connection is independent of it. TCP will deliver the "protocol messages" in order to your client. By "protocol message" I refer of course to the protocol you use on the TCP layer.

Further note that I/O operation are async in nature and very dependent on system load + also compounding network delays & losses, you cannot rely on message ordering **between** TCP connections.

Comment: What do you mean by _between_ TCP connections?

Answer (score 22):

TCP "guarantees" that a receiver will receive the reconstituted stream of bytes as it was originally sent by the sender.  However, between the TCP send/receive endpoints (i.e., the physical network), the data can be received out of order, it can be fragmented, it can be corrupted, and it can even be lost.  TCP accounts for these problems using a handshake mechanism that causes bad packets to be retransmitted.  The TCP stack on the receiver places these packets in the order in which they were transmitted so that when you read from your TCP socket, you are receive the data as it was originally sent.

When you call the [doRead](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.tcp.Connection.html#doRead) method in Twisted, the data is read from the socket up to the size of the buffer.  This data may represent a single message, a partial message, or multiple messages.  It is up to you to extract the messages from the buffer, but you are guaranteed that the bytes are in their transmitted order at this point.

Sorry for muddying the waters with my earlier post...

Comment: please revisit your answer as you are very wrong. The API exposed by TCP is very much a stream with byte ordered delivery. You are referring here to the underlying transport method (i.e. packets) which are of course not guaranteed to arrive in order.

Comment: FYI, the "server layer" for TCP is IP which is of course "connection-less" and does not guarantee packet order delivery.

Comment: I am lost with your explanation -- in second sentence you write data can be corrupted (for TCP client?), and in third you write it will not be corrupted because TCP will handle such case. So what can TCP client see -- data corrupted or guaranteed to be correct? Also with order of data, you mean with direct connection there is order guaranteed, but for indirect connection TCP client can see data out of order?

Answer (score 8):

TCP is a stream, UDP is a message. You're mixing up terms. For TCP it is true that the stream will arrive in the same order as it was send. There are no distict messages in TCP, bytes appear as they arrive, interpreting them as messages is up to you.

Comment: Re: terms - Yep, of course. However, Twisted abstracts this into distinct messages (so interpreting them as messages is not up to me)

Comment: And worth noting that while you might have two writes on the sender side, they might collapse into a single read on the receiver side, and vice versa - depending on the buffer sizes and the network conditions.

Comment: No, Twisted does not abstract TCP into "messages". You will get a chunk of bytes (down to one byte at a time in extreme cases) in the base protocol.

Comment: I think it is right from the application view. From the protocol view, TCP is essentially an UDP with a lot of extensions for connection handling, lost packet re-sending, arrival ordering and so on. It is well visible in the Unix API: the same stream-oriented api calls (write, read) and packet-oriented calls (send, revc) are all working on both type of sockets. Of course you can't manipulate UDP "connection" on a sub-packet level, while you can read/write on the byte-stream level TCP connections.